# jsdoc - Documenting nested array parameters

Tags: jsdoc

I am trying to use jsdoc to document function parameters. A single array (**routes**) is passed in that contains *n* objects. Each object has a **sequences** attribute that takes an array, that again contains *n* objects with a set of attributes.The function is called like in the following example:

```
myFunction(
  [
    {
      isClickable: true,
      isSelected: false,
      popupTitle: 'Route Biel/Bienne >> Freiburg/Fribourg',
      popupContent: ['Von: Biel/Bienne', 'Nach: Freiburg/Fribourg'],
      sequences: [
        {
          latLonTo: [46.68848, 7.68974],
          latLonFrom: [46.94691, 7.44079],
          mot: 'rail',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      isClickable: true,
      isSelected: false,
      popupTitle: 'Route Bern >> Freiburg/Fribourg',
      popupContent: ['Von: Bern', 'Nach: Freiburg/Fribourg'],
      sequences: [
        {
          uicFrom: 8507150,
          uicTo: 8545100,
          mot: 'bus',
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
)
```

My documentation is as follows:

```
 /**
   * Load routes based on a given configuration.
   * @param {Object[]} routes Routes.
   * @param {boolean} routes[].isSelected If true, the route is
   *   selected initially.
   * @param {boolean} routes[].isClickable If true, the route can be
   *   selected or unselected by click.
   * @param {Object[]} routes[].sequences Route sequences.
   * @param {number} routes[].sequences[].uicFrom UIC number of start station.
   * @param {number} routes[].sequences[].uicTo UIC number of end station.
   * @param {array} routes[].sequences[].latLonFrom Lat/Lon coordinate array of start location
   *  (to be used if uicFrom not provided).
   * @param {array} routes[].sequences[].latLonTo Lat/Lon coordinate array of end location
   *  (to be used if uicTo not provided).
   * @param {string} routes[].sequences[].mot Method of transportation.
   *   Allowed values are "rail", "bus", "tram", "subway", "gondola",
   *   "funicular" and "ferry"
   * @returns {Promise<Feature[]>} Promise resolving OpenLayers features.
   */
```

The result is not as expected, as demonstrated in the following picture:
[image]

As indicated in red in the pictures, the parameters in the multidimentional/nested *sequence* array is not parsed properly by jsdoc. Before the second brackets the rest of the string is added to the *description* column instead of the *name* column. The correct output should be:

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I am also open to other,maybe more correct approaches of using jsdoc.

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

I would use two [`@typedef`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) annotations:

- Route
- Sequence

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Sequence
 * @property {Array<number>} latLonTo
 * @property {Array<number>} latLonFrom
 * @property {string} mot
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Route
 * @property isClickable {boolean}
 * @property isSelected {boolean}
 * @property popupTitle {string}
 * @property popupContent {Array<string>}
 * @property sequences {Array<Sequence>}
 */

/**
 * @param {Array<Route>} routes
 */
const func = routes => 42;
```

Which produces the following documentation:

[image]